# How to read in a lot of csvs that match person ID numbers R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains a column of ID numbers that represent individual persons.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

On my harddrive, I also have csv files labeled like 1.csv, 2.csv etc all the way up to say 1000.csv all contained within one folder.

I would like to read in only the csv files that match an ID number in df. Any suggestions for how to do this would be much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all the files with `list.files` from the directory of interest, subset them based on `basename` and either `grep` or `%in%`, then loop over the files, and read them all with `read.csv`

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$", path = "path/to/your/folder",
              full.names = TRUE)
subfiles <- files[sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(files)) %in% df$ID]
lst1 <- lapply(subfiles, read.csv)
```

---

In addition, this can also be done within `list.files` itself

```
pat <- paste0("^(", paste0(df$ID, collapse="|"), ")\\.csv$")
files <- list.files(pattern  = pat, 
        path = "path/to/your/folder", full.names = TRUE)
lst1 <- lapply(files, read.csv)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another potential option is to use the [vroom package](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/). This approach is great if you want to load the data from the chosen csvs into a single dataframe with an ID column (i.e. identify which dataset each row came from), e.g

```
#install.packages("vroom")
library(vroom)
df <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "3"))
list_of_csvs <- paste(df$ID, ".csv", sep = "")
vroom(file = list_of_csvs, id = "ID")
```